# Which value exactly tells the video stream bit rate in ffmpeg output?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a basic doubt. In the following ffmpeg output, which of the bit rate values (in bold) tells us the video bit rate?

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MVI_0135.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    creation_time   : 2011-04-25 14:59:29
  Duration: 00:00:33.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: **20588 kb/s**
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuvj420p, 1280x720, **19028 kb/s**, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-04-25 14:59:29
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-04-25 14:59:29
```

Its a very basic question, but I would appreciate if anyone could tell me...

Answer (score 2):

The 19028 kb/s is in the Video section and is therefore the video bitrate. If you add the Audio bitrate (1536 kb/s) to the Video bitrate (19028 kb/s) you (almost) get the 20588 kb/s combined bitrate for the container.

If that all makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that's the case.